# How to remove this annoying mobile data pop up?

Tags: mobile-data

Whenever I toggle off mobile data, this pops up. Does anyone know how to remove it? It occurs every time I toggle it off.

[image]

Comment: It is a warning message provided by the system. If you want to remove it, you need to root your phone. I don't know about the process, that's why I wrote this in comment.

Comment: Alternatively, an OS update could remove it should they have done so. If there will be another for the device then maybe it will in time.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more information, which device and version OS are you running? For general reference, it would be worth checking out this thread to see what other samsung users have been experiencing https://forums.androidcentral.com/samsung-galaxy-tab/727756-how-remove-mobile-data-turned-off-notification-notification-list.html

Comment: To me i get prompted this when I disable data from settings but when I disable it from status bar tile it doesn't so try that at least.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a package disabler app, find out the name of the package(some apps will show the packages, use adb, or by Google Search) and then disable that message. Most package disabler apps require root but some don't.